# Pass javascript values to Java?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to pass `this.id` to a `get()` method of a list. But its not working. What is the right way to do this ?.

Please help .

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $('div').each(function(){
      jwplayer(this.id).setup({
    playlist: [{
        sources: [
            { file:  "${postUrl.get(this.id).getSrcUrl()}"

            }],
        }],
    sources: [{
            file: "${postUrl.get(1).getSrcUrl()}"
        }]
    });
      });

</script>
```

Comment: Can mention your java code where you want to access the JS value?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.

All the JSP code is executed (on the server) before the Javascript code (in the browser) even gets there.

You cannot directly pass data between these two.

You could use JSP to add a `data-source-url` attribute to those divs, and then use the value in your Javascript function.